# Lambdas don't appear to work within ref classes in VS2010

Tags: lambda, c++-cli, c++11

One of the cool new C++ features in Visual Studio 2010 are lambda expressions. However, I can't get them to work within a managed class.

```
class UnmanagedClass {
    void Foo() {
        // Creating empty lambda within unmanaged class.
        // This compiles fine.
        auto lambda = [](){ ; };
    }
};

ref class ManagedClass {
    void Foo() {
        // Creating empty lambda within managed class.
        // This creates error C3809:
        // A managed type cannot have any friend functions/classes/interfaces.
        auto lambda = [](){ ; };
    }
};
```

My best guess is that the compiler creates the anonymous function class as a friend class, even though I never use class members. This seems to mean that lambdas cannot be used at all within ref classes.

I was so happy when I read that VS2010 adds lambda expressions to C++. Does anybody know how to get them to work within ref classes?

Comment: To be fair, lambda's are part of the C++0x standard. C++/CLI is totally different, and you shouldn't *really* expect everything to transfer just like that. (By the way, maybe it's just your style, but you don't need an empty `;` in the lambda.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Looks like](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=524356) it is being considered for future versions. Otherwise known as: "We'll get to it."